# How to ignore the order of an array in an object field in an e2e test?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, e2e-testing

I'm working with NestJS and TypeOrm and I'm having trouble with the e2e tests.
expect(result).toEqual(expectedResult) tells me that the result does not match with the expectedResult but when I display these two values I get this :

```json
 // result
{
    [...],
    jobs: [ { id: 2, name: 'Job2' }, { id: 1, name: 'Job1' } ], // wrong order
    languages: [ { id: 1, name: 'Language1' }, { id: 2, name: 'Language2' } ],
    tools: [ { id: 1, name: 'Tool1' }, { id: 2, name: 'Tool2' } ],
    activity_areas: [ // wrong order
      { id: 2, name: 'ActivityArea2' },
      { id: 1, name: 'ActivityArea1' }
    ],
    mobility_areas: [ // wrong order
      {
        id: 2,
        location_category: 'region',
        name: 'Location2',
        parentId: 1
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        location_category: 'country',
        name: 'Location1',
        parentId: null
      }
    ],
    desired_jobs: [ { id: 2, name: 'Job2' }, { id: 1, name: 'Job1' } ],// wrong order
    desired_contracts: [ { id: 2, name: 'Contract2' }, { id: 1, name: 'Contract1' } ]// wrong order
}

//expected result
{
    [...],
    jobs: [ { id: 1, name: 'Job1' }, { id: 2, name: 'Job2' } ],
    languages: [ { id: 1, name: 'Language1' }, { id: 2, name: 'Language2' } ],
    tools: [ { id: 1, name: 'Tool1' }, { id: 2, name: 'Tool2' } ],
    activity_areas: [
      { id: 1, name: 'ActivityArea1' },
      { id: 2, name: 'ActivityArea2' }
    ],
    mobility_areas: [
      {
        id: 1,
        location_category: 'country',
        name: 'Location1',
        parentId: null
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        location_category: 'region',
        name: 'Location2',
        parentId: 1
      }
    ],
    desired_jobs: [ { id: 1, name: 'Job1' }, { id: 2, name: 'Job2' } ],
    desired_contracts: [ { id: 1, name: 'Contract1' }, { id: 2, name: 'Contract2' } ]
}
```

The differents between the two results are the orders of some arrays in some fields (jobs, activity_ares, ...) and I don't want this to be perceived as a difference that triggers the test to fail.  I want to keep the order out of the comparison.

It seems that to add :
`order: { id: 'asc' }` in each repo.find(), repo.findOne(), etc. in services work.
But I don't think that this is a good solution and I have too many to add it manually on each one.

Of course, it's not always the same fields that are in the wrong order, so I can't just change the order in the expected result.

I precise an observation: the test work almost every time when I run it alone but when I run all the test together, it failed almost everytime.

Do you have a solution to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by creating a function that sorts each field of an object's array field :

```js
export const sortObj = (obj) => {
    for (const prop in obj) {
        if (Array.isArray(obj[prop])) {
            obj[prop].sort((a,b) => a.id - b.id);
        }
    }
    return obj;
};
```

I use it like this :

```js
expect(sortObj(result)).toEqual(expectedResult)
```